# If cell U2 is under 25% copy E2 in H2, if its >25% copy E2 into I2?

Tags: excel-formula

I am given a set of times. One set is into and out of the facility in the AM and PM, the other is the "activity times" started and finished while in the facility. Example: In the facility at 8am, start activity at 10am, finish activity at 2pm, out of facility at 4pm. If the weekly percentage of activity vs non activity is less than 25% we are to bill one code. If it is 25% or greater, we bill another code. I have all the formulas to give me the percentage I need. But how do I get the times given in Column E to show in either column H is column U is under 25% or Column I if 25% and greater.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJKdE.png)

Comment: If possible, can you add a small sample of test data as a CSV snippet, it need not be more than two or three rows, along with the excel formulae you have so far.  That will permit your test case to be reproduced: this will be necessary to provide a valid solution.  Providing a [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a great help in getting your question answered.

Answer (score 0):

So, in cell H2 enter:

```
 =if(U2<25,E2,0)
```

And in cell I2

```
=if(U2>25,E2,0)
```

Assuming the value in U2 is between 0 and 100